# Saving multiple sheets to multiple workbooks using a table

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a work book with around 300 sheets inside of it, and I want to split these sheets into differnt workbooks, with some sheets going into more than one workbook.

To simplify, say I have the sheets: Duck, dragon, goose, salmon, cod in my workbook.

I would like to save the duck, dragon and goose sheets into a new work book called animals. The salmon, and cod sheets into a workbook called fish. Then the duck, goose, salmon and cod sheets into a workbook called edible.

Ideally I would like to put a Table in the 1st sheet where column A would have the sheet names, and column B would have the new workbook name. Click the macro, and the sheet names that are in A are saved in a new workbook with the title of whats in column B. This way it is a bit more friendly for my team to use the interface.

Any advice, or help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a valid approach.  If you have any problems, post a question and we will be happy to help.  (But just telling us what you intend to do does not make a good question, so this will probably get closed very soon.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

You need:

A table with name = "list_table"

Consist of:

2 columns with headers "sheet_names" and "workbook_names"

In the column "sheet_names" you need to put your list of sheets in the workbook, example: ("duck", "goose").

In the column "workbook_names" you need to put your list of new workbook names.

The macro will copy the specified sheet in a new workbook and save it using the workbook name you filled in the "workbook_names" column.

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Sub export_asignated_workbook()

    Dim list_table As ListObject
    Set list_table = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("list_table")

    Dim sheet_names As Range
    Dim workbook_names As Range

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sheet_name As String
    Dim new_workbook_name As String
    Dim save_path As String

    Set workbook_names = list_table.ListColumns("sheet_names").DataBodyRange

    For i = 1 To workbook_names.Cells.Count

        sheet_name = workbook_names(i)
        new_workbook_name = workbook_names(i).Offset(0, 1)

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name)
        .Copy
        End With

        save_path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & new_workbook_name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs save_path, 51

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the macro. I think it's going to do exactly what I want but it gets caught up near the end:  With Sheets(sheet_name) .Copy End With The sheet name part gets caught in the debugger (run-time error 9). Tried to change the name do sheet_names but it still causes an error (run-time error 13)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, I tested the code before posting it right here, i does not give me an error when running, maybe you should check your sheet names, change the variables names in the code?, try using a sheet name named "duck" if nothing works then try debugging it by yourself it's not a really complicated piece of code also this is a good base to do your own code! :)

Comment: Ah figured it out! It's when I put more than one sheet name into the sheet name column.